# how to load data in partial from controller in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, html, express

I want to access data in a partial file through http.post() method.
The data is accessible in controller but not accessible in the partila file.html.when i put the response in console.log(JSON.stringify(res)).The res is shown in browser console.It means the response comes in controller.
But the response in not shown chill.html partial.how can i access the response in chill.html.
Also i have used the post method because i am posting some data to "/a".

Here is the code for controller

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);
myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider) {
    $stateProvider

        // HOME STATES AND NESTED VIEWS ========================================
        .state('home',{
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'partials/final1.html'
        })
        .state('a',{

            url:'/a',
            templateUrl:'partials/chill.html',
            controller: 'searchctrl'
                    }
        })
myApp.controller('searchctrl',function($scope,$http,$location){
   // app.searchctrl($scope,$http,$location)
        $scope.search=function(){
        $http.post('/a',$scope.user).success(function(res){
         $scope.items=res;
         console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
         $location.path('/a');
        }).
        error(function(res){

            alert(1234);
        })

        }
        });
```

chill.html

```
    <div class="right-content">
      <div class="right-content-heading">
        <div class="right-content-heading-left">
          <h3>Latest Colletcions of videos</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="right-content-heading-right">
          <div class="social-icons">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#" target="_blank" class="facebook"> </a></li>
              <li><a href="#" target="_blank" class="twitter"></a></li>
              <li><a href="#" target="_blank" class="googleplus"></a></li>
              <li><a href="#" target="_blank" class="pinterest"></a></li>
              <li><a href="#" target="_blank" class="dribbble"></a></li>
              <li><a href="#" target="_blank" class="vimeo"></a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"> </div>
      </div>
      <!-- -pictures--->
      <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="man in items">{{ man.name }}</li>
</ul>

      <div class="clear"></div>
      <!-- //////////////////////////////////-->
    </div>
```

I am using node + express at backend
app.js

```
app.post('/a',function(req,res){
var string=req.body.name;
//console.log(string);
items = [
        {
            name: 'Macallan 12',
            price: 50
        },
        {
            name: 'Chivas Regal Royal Salute',
            price: 10000
        },
        {
            name: 'Glenfiddich 1937',
            price: 20000
        }
    ];
res.json(items);
});
```

So, how can i load the data in chill.html file which comes in controller searachctrl.

Comment: data is set to ``$scope.items`` inside a search function , when / how this function will be called ??

Comment: this function is called through a submit form. this works fine. I submit some data to app.post() router using http.post and get that data using req.body in server. then from app.post() i send the server data back to client using res.json(items) and get that data in the same function/controller (searchctrl) using http.post method. the data comes from server in "res" variable. Also i have console.log(res )to check if the the data came or not. All this works fine and res has data in it.